# how can I .gitignore files under a directory except ones with a pattern?

Tags: git, gitignore

Imagine I have a config-files directory. I want all under this dir and subdirs except the ones with starting name of `example.` to be ignored.

I tried some approaches but none of them work and most of them result in all files under config-files directory to be untracked. Here are two examples of what I tried to do:

```
# Ignore everything in the config-files directory
/config-files/**

# Allow tracking of files starting with "example."
!/config-files/**/example.*
```

```
# Ignore everything in the config-files directory
/config-files/*

# Allow tracking of files starting with "example."
!/config-files/example.*
!/config-files/**/example.*
```

**Note:** the config-files itself is consisted of sub-directories like `db`, `jwt` and etc.

Comment: Have you tried to run `git check-ignore -v YOURFILE`?

Comment: @Friedrich I was not familiar with the command. yet it gives the same results for both types of files:
`.gitignore:5:/config-files/**   config-files/db/influx.yaml`

`.gitignore:5:/config-files/**   config-files/db/example.psql.yaml`

Comment: I see it gives a result that is both correct and not helpful in the least. Well, it was worth a shot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key rule from [the documentation](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) is this:

> It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded. Git doesn’t list excluded directories for performance reasons, so any patterns on contained files have no effect, no matter where they are defined.

For instance, if you have this directory tree [1]:

```
.
└── config-files
    ├── example.txt
    ├── ignore-me.txt
    └── sub-dir
        ├── example.txt
        └── ignore-me.txt
```

Using the rule `/config-files/*` or `/config-files/**` will ignore the path `config-files/sub-dir`, and git *doesn't even examine the files inside it*.

To work around that, you need to specify rules that *only match files*, not whole directories. For instance:

```
# Ignore files inside config-files, and its sub-directories
/config-files/**/*.*

# Allow tracking of files starting with "example."
!/config-files/**/example.*
```

- The first rule will ignore the specific files: `config-files/example.txt`, `config-files/ignore-me.txt`, `config-files/sub-dir/example.txt` and `config-files/sub-dir/ignore-me.txt`
- The second rule will re-include `config-files/example.txt` and `config-files/sub-dir/example.txt`

---

[1] Here's a quick bash script to create that sample, and see the effect for yourself:

```bash
cd $(mktemp -d)
mkdir -p config-files/sub-dir
touch config-files/{,sub-dir}/{example,ignore-me}.txt
tree # or "ls -R" if you don't have "tree" installed

git init
echo '/config-files/**/*.*' > .gitignore
echo '!/config-files/**/example.*' >> .gitignore
git add .
git status
```