# Exclude the "build" folder from a repository (.gitignore), except files with extension ".bin" located in any folder/subfolder

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm using .gitignore to exclude the "build" folder from a repository, but i would like to keep .bin files located anywhere.

I tried this:

```
/build/**
!**/*.bin
```

And tried this:

```
/build/*
!**/*.bin
```

The result: .gitignore keep .bin files in "build" folder, but doesn't keep .bin files located in subfolders ("build/bootloader", for example)

I also tried:

```
/build/*
!build/*.bin
!build/bootloader/*.bin
```

What else can i try to keep .bin files from subfolders?, Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can I .gitignore files under a directory except ones with a pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76101151/how-can-i-gitignore-files-under-a-directory-except-ones-with-a-pattern)

Comment: @IMSoP Thanks!. I tried that, but still have the same problem. .bin files located in build/bootloader are still ignored

Comment: Creating a sample directory, and translating that answer directly to your case (`/build/**/*.*` and `!build/**/*.bin`), gives the desired effect for me. Perhaps you could construct a [mre] - a sample directory structure, with a mixture of files you do and don't want to ignore?

Comment: As a starting point, here's the concise set of bash commands I used: `cd $(mktemp -d); git init; mkdir -p {build,zzz}/{foo,bar,baz}; touch {build,zzz}/{,foo,bar,baz}/{foo,bar}.{bin,txt}; echo -e '/build/**/*.*\n!build/**/*.bin' > .gitignore; git add .; git status` That results in a bunch of different files and directories; everything gets staged except for the `foo.txt` and `bar.txt` files inside `build` and its sub-directories.

Answer (score 1):

You miss the starting `/` and you need to exclude files not a full directory

```
/build/*.*
!/build/**/*.bin
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your .gitgnore:

```
# Ignore files in build/ and its subfolders
/build/**/*.*
# Allow bin files in build/ and its subfolders
!/build/**/*.bin
```

Comment: You don't actually need the first and third rules: the `/**/` matches *zero ore more* directories, so `build/foo.bar` is included in `build/**/foo.bar` Once you take those out, it's exactly the same as [the answer I proposed as a duplicate above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76101246/157957), just with less explanation.

Comment: @IMSoP you are totally right. This should be closed as duplicate.